# Most Flash games don't resize properly in a browser window. How can I easily make my game do this?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Most flash-based browser games don't seem to resize properly when the user resizes their browser window (i.e. ctrl+mousewheel).

Example of bad resizing: [Boxhead The Zombie Wars](http://www.crazymonkeygames.com/Boxhead-The-Zombie-Wars.html). Please refrain from playing for a moment, lest you forget about my question.

Some (surprisingly very few) actually do resize properly. Example (at least in Chrome): [D.N.8](http://www.kongregate.com/games/GamingYourWay/dn8)

Is there a simple or standard technique to accomplish proper resizing? How do you do it?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I wanted to thank you for reminding me of how fun Boxhead is.  I just wasted a few minutes, and more are on the way.  Great game!

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, for starters you need to ensure that the stage doesn't scale itself automatically when the player viewport is changed, and pick an alignment for where you stage will 'stick' as the viewport grows:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Once that is done, you have to listen to the stage's RESIZE event, so that when the player window/viewport is resized, you can check the new size and relayout your UI accordingly:

```
var resizeTimeout:uint;

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);
function onResize(e:Event=null):void 
{
    // Try setting a delay to workaround a weird bug when leaving fullscreen mode where the
    // dimensions aren't updated properly, even though a resize event is triggered..?
    if (resizeTimeout)
        clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);

    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(
        function ()
        {
            trace("resizing: " + stage.stageWidth+"x"+stage.stageHeight);
            // Re-layout from here
        },
        250);
}
```

As you can see I work around a bug here, which may not be neccesary in your case. Without the scaling mode turned off, the player will automatically resize your stage to fit the viewport, keeping your application oblivious to the changes. This can result in problems when the width/height ratio changes.

Anyway I hope I got most of this right, it's been a while since I had to deal with this, I just happened to have this bit of code lying around still from an old project.

Comment: Looking at the game you gave as a bad example though, it seems they did turn off scaling, and made it stick TOP_LEFT, but didn't bother to re-layout anything when the viewport is resized.. which is a bit odd since it would've been better if it had just scaled in the default way, I think

Comment: This is a fine answer about no_scale, but it's more or less the opposite to what the asker needs. You should explain that for most content it's best to use one of the other scale modes and let Flash scale the content up or down automatically. That's presumably what's happening in the "good" example provided. Using no_scale is typically done to *prevent* that, when you want the content not to resize (as in the "bad" example), or if you want to dynamically change layouts based on container size.